# Variable value is nil outside the closure and in the tableview dataSource method

Tags: swift, uitableview, variables, closures

I have been looking at this problem for two days. Searched Google and StackOverflow and i didn't find an appropriate answer.

There are some questions in StackOverflow addressing this issue. But non were helpful in my situation.

I am trying to put a value into a variable (myArray) which is of type (WeatherDataModel) inside the closure for a JSON response.

Then I want to use that global variable to populate my (myTableView) with the data from myArray.

I get nil outside the closure.

Any help is really appreciated guys.

Thanks.

Here is the code in the code in my viewController

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  WeatherApp
//
//  Created by Angela Yu on 23/08/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 London App Brewery. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class WeatherViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var myArray = Array<WeatherDataModel>()
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = myTableVIew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = myArray[indexPath.row].cityName
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return myArray.count
    }



    @IBOutlet weak var myTableVIew: UITableView!
    //Constants
    let WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    let APP_ID = "6a2cf7e5f146f5a1b8c2af7c93055a40"
    let longtitude = String (45.437896)
    let latitude = String (35.565415)
    var params : [String : String] = Dictionary<String , String>()

    //TODO: Declare instance variables here
    var weatherDataModel = WeatherDataModel()


    //Pre-linked IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //TODO:Set up the location manager here.
        params = ["lon" : longtitude, "lat" : latitude , "appid" : APP_ID]

       getWeatherData(url: WEATHER_URL, params: params)    }



    //MARK: - Networking
    /***************************************************************/

    //Write the getWeatherData method here:

    func getWeatherData ( url : String , params: [String : String] ){
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters : params).responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print ("got weather Data")

                let weatherJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value)


                self.updateWeatherData(json: weatherJSON)

            }else {
                print(response.result.error)
            }
        }
    }







    //MARK: - JSON Parsing
    /***************************************************************/


    //Write the updateWeatherData method here:
    func updateWeatherData (json : JSON) {

        print(json)
        weatherDataModel.cityName = json["name"].stringValue
        weatherDataModel.pressure = json["main"]["pressure"].intValue
        weatherDataModel.weatherDiscription = json["weather"][0]["main"].stringValue
        print(weatherDataModel.cityName, weatherDataModel.pressure, weatherDataModel.weatherDiscription)

        for i in 0...3 {
            myArray.append(weatherDataModel)
        }
    }








}
```

And here is the WeatherDataModel:

```
//
//  WeatherDataModel.swift
//  WeatherApp
//
//  Created by Angela Yu on 24/08/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 London App Brewery. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

internal class WeatherDataModel {

    internal var cityName: String

    internal var pressure: Int

    internal var weatherDiscription: String
}
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: One first thing I noticed as I'm studying this...  myArray is not a global.  It's a member of WeatherViewController.  It'd have to be outside the class to be a global.  I'm not saying it should be moved out, but you'll want to edit your question to correct this.

Comment: I might have understood this wrong. Thank you for the heads-up

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy that this is probably a duplicate of that other SO.  That SO refers to global vars when they actually mean member vars too.  That SO's solution was to reload the table's data by calling reloadData() (which you should do within updateWeatherData() ).  That might be all you need, but as I'm unclear what you mean by "I get nit nil outside the closure", I suspect there may be a further problem for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Smartcat. Problem solved!

Comment: Why are you adding 3 references to the same `weatherDataModel` to your array?

Comment: The project is just for testing purposes . I have a similar project I am working on. Although I still don't get the results I want in my other project.